# JS won't link to HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, rot13

I have a Rot13 JS function that I am attempting to link to a button. The expected output is meant to be that if I enter 'ABC' and press the Encrypt button, the encrypted text becomes 'NOP'.

The function doesn't currently link up to the buttons in HTML and when I press the encrypt button there is no response. I've included a script tag in the HTML.

**EDIT:** the encrypter is linked to the button, however it encrypts 'ABC' to 'ABC.

**JavaScript:**

```js
function rot13() {
  var input = document.getElementById("box1").value;
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var asciiNum = input[i].charCodeAt();
    if (asciiNum >= 65 && asciiNum <= 77) {
      output.push(String.fromCharCode(asciiNum + 13))
    } else if (asciiNum >= 78 && asciiNum <= 90) {
      output.push(String.fromCharCode(asciiNum - 13))
    } else {
      output.push(input[i])
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("box2").value = output.join('');
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="plain text here..." name="plaintext" id="box1">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="rot13()">Encrypt</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="rot13()">Decrypt</button>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="encrypted message here..." name="encryptedtext" id="box2">
      </div>
```

EDIT: corrected the JS.

Comment: open console & check the error if any

Comment: `output.join('') = document.getElementById("box2");` — what do you expect that to do?

Comment: Change `output.join('') = document.getElementById("box2");` to `document.getElementById("box2").value = output.join('')`

Comment: And fill `output` the right way.

Comment: @dporechny Done this. No error in console but Brackets says: ERROR: document is not defined. [no-undef]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with code:

- `output.join('') = document.getElementById("box2")` will throw error. You should set `.value` to `output.join('')`. The left hand side of `=` should be a `variable`. `output.join('')` returns are value and it cannot be assigned to anything.
- `output + input[i]` will do nothing. You should use `push()` to add values to array.

```js
function rot13() {
  var input = document.getElementById("box1").value;
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var asciiNum = input[i].charCodeAt();
    if (asciiNum >= 65 && asciiNum <= 77) {
      output.push(String.fromCharCode(asciiNum + 13))
    } else if (asciiNum >= 78 && asciiNum <= 90) {
      output.push(String.fromCharCode(asciiNum - 13))
    } else {
      output.push(input[i])
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("box2").value = output.join('');
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="plain text here..." name="plaintext" id="box1">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="rot13()">Encrypt</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="rot13()">Decrypt</button>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="encrypted message here..." name="encryptedtext" id="box2">
      </div>
```

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. Only problem now is that the encrypter is 'encrypting' ABC to ABC.